# File upload issue with Spring MVC REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, file-upload

I have Spring MVC based REST application. Trying to upload a file. Here is the code snippet.

*webmvc-config.xml*

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"
    id="multipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="2000000" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <property name="defaultContentType">
        <ref bean="htmlMediaType" />
    </property>
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            <entry key="file" value="multipart/form-data"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <property name="marshaller">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
```

*FileUploadController.java*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/appfiles")
public class FileUploadController {

private String saveDirectory = "C:/Downloads/"; 
@RequestMapping(value = "/appfiles", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="multipart/form-data", produces="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<List<Map<String, String>>> save(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println("received file with original filename: " + file.getOriginalFilename());

    // List<MultipartFile> files = uploadForm.getFiles();
    List<Map<String, String>> response = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, String> responseMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (null != file) {
        // for (MultipartFile multipartFile : files) {

        String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        fileNames.add(fileName);

        try {
            file.transferTo(new File(saveDirectory
                    + file.getOriginalFilename()));
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    responseMap.put("displayText", file.getOriginalFilename());
    responseMap.put("fileSize", ""+file.getSize());
    response.add(responseMap);

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("Accept", "application/json");
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Map<String, String>>>(response, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

I get the following error when I use chrome extension "postman"

```
Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is     org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:163)
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:139)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1020)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:883)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

postname submission is done with the following details:

```
Headers
conent-type: multipart/form-data
Form-data:
file=<filename.txt>
Method=POST
```

Can you please let me know what is wrong with my code?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: How are you POSTing your data?

Comment: I am using postman addon for chrome as my REST client. I set content-type=multipart/form-data and accept=application/json in header fields. Uploaded the file using form-data fields. I created an attribute called "file" in form-data and upload the file there. and no other attributes set while making "POST" call.

Comment: It sounds like the request was missing the form boundaries.  Do you have any means of looking at the actual HTTP request?  I have a feeling your request is missing some crucial pieces.  Also, it might help to try to post using a dummy HTML form, just get a baseline as to what the request SHOULD look like.

Comment: Expanding on my last comments:  Things to check - You set a boundary in your Content-Type header and your boundary matches whats used in the body.  Some explaination can be found here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue, but when I try it without any Header value it was work fine.